# using Android SDK 2.2 with Rhomobile

Tags: android, compilation, android-2.2-froyo, rhomobile

I have installed: rhodes 2.0.0 beta 11, ruby 1.8, gem 1.3.7, and OpenSUSE 11.2. The only way i can get the app to compile is by using Android SDK 1.5. when I delete 1.5 and install 2.2 it says: No required platform (API level 3) found, can't proceed. any ideas? I would rather use an updated version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have the Android NDK installed. See the prereqs for Android, install the NDK and try again.  Or just do hosted Android build on RhoHub.